# How to add callback to my functions in class

Tags: java, android

im trying to find a way how to add a callback to my function in class. I saw this method in all sdk.

base example its  onClickListener in view

```
myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(--blabla method --));
```

Can any explaine me or give me some good information where i can read about this way ?

for example i want make something like :
I have Login function in class

> MyClass

```
MyClass {
public static void Login() {

}
```

i have listener something like :

```
public interface OnLoginListener {
void onLoginListener(boolean result);
}
```

somewhere in code i call

```
MyClass.Login();
```

But how i can call this function like this :

```
MyClass.Login(new OnLoginListener(--blabla--));
```

Its was question 1
And question 2 
 everything same but i can add something like asyncTask

```
MyClass.Login().callAsync();
```

How to do it in code  ?)
i know its must be basic. But i just cant understand what to find. Please explaine me or give me some info :)

**UPD** Sorry for Question2 i put wrong info
i want add prepareAsync to login.
In some sdk its look like

```
MyClass.Login().prepareAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a listener interface in the class from where you want to send data to activity

```
public interface OnLoginListener {
    void onLoginListener(boolean result);
}
```

Add a method in the same class to register the listener with the object where you want to send data;

```
public void setOnLoginListener(OnLoginListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

When you have to send data through the listener on some action send data from your class to the activity or any registered class like this

```
if(mListener!=null){
  mListener.onLoginListener(YOUR BOOLEAN RESULT);
}
```

Then in your activity class create an object of the listener class and call the method like this.

```
SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass();
sampleClass.setOnLoginListener(new SampleClass.OnLoginListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoginListener(boolean result) {

    }
});
```

Comment: maybe u have also some info about question2?)

Comment: yes it can do..for that add asyntask inside that class and call from main activity using any object

Answer (score 0):

try this .

**MyClass**

```
public class MyClass {

    OnLoginListener mOnLoginListener;


    public void callAsync() {

    }

    public interface OnLoginListener {
        void onLoginListener(boolean result);
    }

    public void Login(OnLoginListener mOnLoginListener) {
        this.mOnLoginListener = mOnLoginListener;
    }
}
```

And call it in the activity or fragment .

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.callAsync();
myClass.Login(new MyClass.OnLoginListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoginListener(boolean result) {
            // do something  here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public interface OnLoginListener {
    void onLoginListener(boolean result);
}

MyClass {
    public static void Login(OnLoginListener listener) {
        // use the listener here
    }
}
```